# Convert mm-dd-yyyy to date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have data in mm-dd-yyyy format. I need it to compare with current date in javascript.

I have got something for data, but it is not working.

My date is 12-07-2016 in mm-dd-yyyy format.

```
var d = '12-07-2016';
var date= d.split("-");
var f = new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0]);
```

Here I am getting date as :

> Tue Jul 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

But I need it as :

> 07 Dec 2016.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have no problem in using third party library use moment.js

Comment: moment.js is wonderful library for date formatting and converstions

Comment: How does November and month==12 go together?

Comment: Months are zero based in JavaScript

Comment: That would make November 10, not 12.

Comment: If your result is July (7) 12th and you wanted December (12) 7th, what do *you* think could be a solution to that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just have your indices the wrong way around for month and day...

```
var f = new Date(date[2], date[0] - 1, date[1]);
```

That will give you 07 DEC 2016

```js
var d = '12-07-2016';
var date= d.split("-");
var f = new Date(date[2], date[0] - 1, date[1]);
console.log(f.toString());
```

Comment: @SurendraMourya: Yeah I spotted that and removed that comment from my answer