# Javascript handle daylight savings time for different time zones

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

Here I got an input box on my web page for users to input a date. For some reason I can't use a datetime picker and I have to pass it to an .NET based service as a `String` via ajax.

Users may from different time zones. And the date is stored as UTC in database.

It seems I have 2 options to handle the timezone:

1. Convert the date string to UTC date string at frontend and pass to service.
2. Pass the UTC offset to service and convert the date string to UTC at backend.

---

However, neither option can handle the **daylight savings time**.

Could anyone give me some suggestions on this?

Comment: the least worst option is to use a library like http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Parsing a date string to a date is 2 lines of code, see [*Convert mm-dd-yyyy to date in javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404663/convert-mm-dd-yyyy-to-date-in-javascript). Getting a UTC date string from a Date is one: *date.toISOString()*.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript's `toUTCString()` and functions like `getUTCDate()` instead of `getDate()` will ignore the timezone offset, including I presume the DST offsets.