# JavaScript - Converting text variable to Date

Tags: javascript, date, parsing

Im working on a React project where im sending `HTTP POST` request to my `API`. Inside the API, my entity has a field which is type of `DateTime` (.NET).

In my React app though my `date` variable is a text.  *Example:* `let dateText = '18-03-2021'`.

Im trying to figure out how can i take this text and make a Date type of variable which has a format that my API can process and take without causing an exception.

As far as the backend goes (.NET), i just need a date, hours do not matter since they are not stored in the database.

To be honest im not that much familiar with formatting dates in JS. What i've found on google didnt help me since it didnt convert it to my needed format. Is there any library that can help me, or can i somehow do it without one?

What i've tried is not much, but following:

```
let dateText = '18-3-2021'
1. let date = new Date(dateText) -> returns `Invalid date`
2. let date = Date.parse(dateText) -> returns `NaN`
```

I can maybe try to make a `custom function` that formats the date, but is this good practice?

EDIT: I just found out this format `03-18-2021` works but the one im trying to pass isnt: `18-03-2021`. Which brings me to my question above the EDIT.

Comment: 18 minus 3 minus 2021 equals negative 2006

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please [search](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+parse+date) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: What I mean by that? Your variable `dateText` is not a string, but an integer. You are missing the quotes: `let dateText = '18-3-2021`

Comment: Check the documentation for using a Date object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/date

Comment: @yunzen This is a typo on my side. My variable is in fact text with quotes `'18-3-2021'`. Sorry for this.

Comment: This can surely be done with a custom function but im not sure is this good practice and the only way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert mm-dd-yyyy to date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404663/convert-mm-dd-yyyy-to-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did is just make a custom *function*:

```
const formatDate = (date) =>{
    let parts = date.split('-');
    const day = parts[0];
    const month = parts[1];
    const year = parts[2];
    let formattedDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    return formattedDate;
}
```

Still not sure though if this is good practice, but that is how i achieved it.

Comment: The a manual parsing approach is OK, but a format like m-d-y is ambiguous and confusing. y-m-d would be preferable.